# Spring category subcategory json issue

Tags: json, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity like following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "color")
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String color;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Category> subcategories = new HashSet<Category>();}
```

and I'm using `findAll()` from `JPA repo`, what I have so far is the list of categories and parent as child:

```
 {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Home",
    "parent": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "News",
      "color": "#d50000"
    }
  },
```

What I want is the opposite, parent and a list of children, what do I need to change?

Comment: classic method from JPARepository

Comment: Are there definitely child subcategories?

Comment: no ofc there is parents that has parent = null and the sub cat ones

Comment: And JPARepository is nothing to do with the JPA API, so tagged now as Spring-Data-JPA

Comment: probably I tagged it by mistake